# How do I get a Boolean value for a partial match using Groovy's regex?

Tags: regex, groovy

Groovy has a regular expression "match operator" (`==~`). The [documentation](http://docs.groovy-lang.org/latest/html/documentation/index.html#_regular_expression_operators) says it returns a Boolean, but requires a "strict match". It does not define "strict match".

I'm not familiar with any regex system where this expression is `false`. But, that's what Groovy is telling me.

```
'foo-bar-baz' ==~ /bar/ // => false
```

The find operator (`=~`) returns a `Matcher`, which can be indexed for matches and capture groups, apparently. But, I'd have to write an explicit test to have this expression return a Boolean.

```
('foo-bar-baz' =~ /bar/)[0] != null // => true
```

Two questions...

1. What is a "strict match"?
2. How do I get a Boolean value without adding a ton of garbage to my expression?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

The `'foo-bar-baz' ==~ /bar/` is equal to `"foo-bar-baz".matches("bar")`, that is, it requires a full string match.

The `=~` operator allows *partial* match, that is, it may find a match/matches inside a string.

Hence:

```
println('foo-bar-baz' ==~ /bar/) // => false
println('bar' ==~ /bar/)         // => true
println('foo-bar-baz' =~ /bar/)  // => java.util.regex.Matcher[pattern=bar region=0,11 lastmatch=]
```

See this [Groovy demo](http://ideone.com/shnoJi)

If you need to check for a partial match, you cannot avoid building a *`Matcher`* object:

> use the find operator `=~` to build a *`java.util.regex.Matcher`* instance
>
> ```
>    def text = "some text to match"
>    def m = text =~ /match/                                           
>    assert m instanceof Matcher                                       
>    if (!m) {                                                         
>        throw new RuntimeException("Oops, text not found!")
>    }
> ```
>
> `if (!m)` is equivalent to calling `if (!m.find())`

Alternatively, you may use the `!` twice to cast the result to correct Boolean value:

```
println(!!('foo-bar-baz' =~ /bar/))
```

[Returns *true*](http://ideone.com/K76C9S).

Comment: Ok, that starts to answer some questions... I edited the question to expand the scope to my actual problem (now that I understand more, it's not just about "strict matching").